# Trying to convert Go Pro GYRO Data to rotation in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, euler-angles, gopro

I'm trying to convert Go Pro gyro data to Three.js coordinates so that I can project the footage onto the inside of a sphere, rotate the sphere and have 3D stabilisation.

[image]

The camera is orientated as such, and the order of the coordinates is Z,X,Y

I'm attempting to apply this vector to rotate the sphere, something like this

```
    this._nextVec3.set(this._next[0],this._next[1],this._next[2])
    this.el.object3D.rotation.setFromVector3(this._nextVec3)
```

But I can't get the rotation to match the rotation of the camera, and I assume it's something to do with the left/right hand configuration?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, make sure you specify the correct [`rotation.order` attribute](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Euler.order). Since you said it's `ZXY`, then it should be a simple

```
this.el.object3D.rotation.order = "ZXY";
```

Secondly, check out the Three.js axes, taken from the [editor](https://threejs.org/editor/):

[image]

As you can see, the WebGL axes are different than the GoPro. I think you'll have to flip the X-axis, and swap the Z and Y. So maybe something like:

```
let xRot = this._next[0];
let yRot = this._next[1];
let zRot = this._next[2];
this.el.object3D.rotation.set(-xRot, zRot, yRot);
```

Comment: @beek Out of curiosity, how are you getting GoPro rotational data? Does the MAX output a JSON of it alongside the video file?

Comment: this little genius https://github.com/JuanIrache/gopro-telemetry